# Why Classes to java have been added which are not thread safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety

I am seeing a lot of classes being added to Java which are not thread safe.

Like StringBuilder is not thread safe while StringBuffer was and StringBuilder is recoomended over Stringbuffer.

Also various collection classes are not thread safe.

Isn't being thread safe a good thing ?

Or i am just stupid and don't yet understand the meaning of being thread safe ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because thread safety makes things slower, and not everything has to be multi-threaded.

Consider reading this article to find out basics about thread safety :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety

When you comfortable enough with the threads/or not, consider reading this book, it has great reviews :

[http://www.amazon.com/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601)

Comment: @Lokesh Sah: then use the `StringBuilder` in a syncrhonized block or use `StringBuffer`.

Comment: @Lokesh Sah: There is no problem with using `StringBuilder` in one thread of a multi-threaded program. If you want to append strings from multiple threads, then what semantics do you want? Shall one thread own the `StringBuilder` for some time in order to append several strings without anything in between from other threads. Or do you want arbitrary interleavings of appended strings. In the latter case use `StringBuffer`.

Answer (score 4):

Some classes are not suitable for using across multiple threads. StringBuffer is one of them IMHO.

It is very hard to find even a contrived example of when you would use StringBuffer in a multi-threaded way that cannot be more simple achieve other ways.

Answer (score 3):

Thread safety is not a all or nothing property. Ten years ago some books recommended marking all methods of a class as synchronized in order to make them thread safe. This costs some performane, but it is far from a guarantee that your overall program is thread safe. Therefore, you have costs with a questionable gain. That is, why there are still classes added to Java library which are not thread safe.

The "make every method synchronized" strategy is only able to provide guarantees about the consistency of one object, and it has the potential to introduce dead-locks, or to be weaker than thought (think about `wait()`).

Answer (score 2):

There is a performance overhead to inherently thread-safe code. If you do not need the class in a concurrent context but need the performance to be high then these, original classes are not ideal.

Comment: @Lokesh Sah: if you have state, in this case a mutable string, and mulitple threads acting upon it, then it is possible for the state to get corrupted. E.g. if the string was 'run', thread A may change it to 'running' by adding 'ning' whilst thread B may want to change it to 'ran' by changing the second character from 'u' to 'a'. If both threads attempt this change at the same time, you could end up with corrupt state e.g. 'ranning' in this case. To prvent this, each thread would need to lock the mutable string, look at its current value, make the change necessary and release the lock.

Answer (score 2):

A typical usage of StringBuilder is something like:

`return new StringBuilder().append("this").append("that").toString()`

all in one thread, no need to synchronize anything.

Comment: If you were to use StringBuffer in multiple threads you could still get `thisthisthatthat` or `thisthatthisthat` etc.

Comment: True, but things can get much much worse if StringBuilder is used by multiple threads. Take a look at the append() method and think what might happen when two threads modify the state the StringBuilder concurrently

Comment: Either way its a bad design o share a StringBu*er accross threads and you will get corrupt text. But StringBuilder would be badder. ;)